# Python Classes Best Practices

Tags: python, class, methods, instance, attr

I wonder if while working with OPP/Classes/Instances in Python I should be always using **getAttr()/setAttr()** when reading-writing from-to a Class's attribute/variable. Or dealing with the variable/attribute directly (such as self.my_attr = "some_value") would be a better practice?

#### *Direct access to Class attr*

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.my_attr = 'My_Value'

    def doSomething(self):
        localVariable = self.my_attr
        print localVariable
```

#### *Using a Class's method to access a Class's attr*

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.my_attr = 'My_Value'

    def getMyAttr(self):
        return self.my_attr

    def doSomething(self):
        localVariable = self.my_attr
        print localVariable
```

## EDITED LATER:

While reading 'The Object-Oriented Thought Process' book (Matt Weisfeld : Developer's Library) ... The author states continuously throughout it:

*"...Access to attributes within an object should be controlled by the object
itself—no other object should directly change an attribute of another..."*

*"...If you control the access to the attribute, when a problem arises, you do
not have to worry about tracking down every piece of code that might have changed the
attribute—it can only be changed in one place (the setter)..."*

I will be sticking to setters and getters then. Suggested/mentioned here Python's @property and @.setter make it even easier.

Comment: Concerning your edit: Other peoples' thought are generally not be adopted without reflection. Only because it is printed in a book, a fact doesn't become true. "Best" practices are only "best" for a given value of "best" and a given value of "practices". Putting every wee bit into setters and getters leads to Java's getter-setter-hell (I feel any Java code is 90% boiler plate code), having trust that "we are all adults here" (as the zen of python suggests) might be even worse. Maybe the truth is somewhere out there, between the two extrema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of the latter example, consider using the `@property` decorator.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.__my_attr = 'My_Value'

    @property
    def my_attr(self):
        return self.__my_attr

    def doSomething(self):
        localVariable = self.__my_attr
        print localVariable
```

Use it only if you have good reason to protect the member, e.g. if you want to validate its values:

```
class Person:
    @property
    def age(self): return self.__age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value < 0: raise Exception('Age out of bounds.')
        self.__age = value

p = Person ()
p.age = 14
print (p.age)
p.age = -34
```

Answer (score 12):

You should access the variable directly.

If you subsequently need to add some logic for getting/setting the value, convert it to a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).